# how to draw several shape (circle, line, rec, etc.) with more control?

Tags: graphics, java-me, lcdui

I know there is a nice class Graphics with basic api like drawLine, drawRect. But I need more control to set pixel size, wide, thick, thin, lines in my shape. My intention is to draw a dynamic shape (similar to attached image) depending on different criteria.

I'm new in J2ME. Any other suggestion to achieve my goal is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set line thickness in J2ME.

However, you can try some workarounds:

To simulate thick lines, you can just draw multiple lines.
And to draw a thick circle you can draw a larger filled circle and then a smaller one inside it.

[image]

For dotted lines use [`setStrokeStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17412_01/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#setStrokeStyle(int)).

Answer (score 0):

If your target devices are Nokia than you can use `drawPixels(...)` and `drawPolygon(...)` in conjunction with MIDP graphics methods `drawLine(...)`, `drawRect(...)` and `drawArc(...)`. To achieve your goal. The drawPixels(...) is a very powerful method in the sense you can draw virtually any custom shape you would like. I know of SonyEricsson that supports nokia UI api's but with "*strings attached*".

More descriptive information can be found at this [link](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-237420DE-CCBE-4A74-A129-572E0708D428/com/nokia/mid/ui/DirectGraphics.html).

.

If your target devices are not just Nokia than i would suggest you find / do-self port of Nokia UI class `DirectGraphics`. There are no ODM specific libraries the way Nokia have it.